# Is there a reason the Japanese Language Icon is 3D sometimes?

Tags: bug

This image has both JP stack exchange and meta. Meta displays normally, but the main site became `3D`
[image]

This image it's just wrong:

[image]

Maybe this is due to dark mode in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does appear to be a bug in Stack Overflow's dark mode, as you suggest:

> [image: screen shot comparing light mode to dark mode]

In fact, there is already a post on this topic over on Meta Stack Overflow:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397173/wrong-icon-showing-up-in-inbox

An employee has already responded over there, and it's currently [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), so hopefully it'll get sorted out soon :-)